# WAP in java to input a three digit number and calculate each digit's frequency

Tags: java, if-statement, integer

I made a program for the question and it's working fine, but in some cases it's not working like when I enter 656, it's showing like this:

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqFPj.png)

The code is showed below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner rx = new Scanner(System.in);
    int ui,uiy,troll3,troll1;
    float uix,uis,uiz,uit;
    System.out.println("Enter a valid three digit number to calculate the frequency of the digits in it. \n");
    ui = rx.nextInt();
    if(ui>99&&ui<=999) {

        uis = (float) ui;
        //System.out.println(uis+" uis");
        uix = uis / 10;
        //System.out.println(uix+" uix");
        uiy = (int) uix;
        //System.out.println(uiy+" uiy");
        troll3 = (int) ((uix - uiy) * 10); //1st digit
        //System.out.println("3d " + troll3);
        uiz = uix / 10;
        //System.out.println(uiz+ " uiz");
        troll1 = (int) uiz;
        //System.out.println("1d " + troll1);
        uit = (uiz - troll1) * 10;
        //System.out.println(uit+" uit");
        int troll2 = (int) uit;
        //System.out.println("2d " + troll2);
        if (troll1 == troll2 && troll1 == troll3) {
            System.out.println("The number " + troll1 + " appears three times.");
        } else if (troll1 != troll2 && troll2 != troll3 && troll1 != troll3) {
            System.out.println("The number " + troll1 + " appears one time.");
            System.out.println("The number " + troll2 + " appears one time.");
            System.out.println("The number " + troll3 + " appears one time.");
        } else if (troll1 == troll2) {
            System.out.println("The number " + troll1 + " appears two times.");
            System.out.println("The number " + troll3 + " appears one time.");
        } else if (troll1 == troll3) {
            System.out.println("The number " + troll3 + " appears two times.");
            System.out.println("The number " + troll2 + " appears one time.");
        } else if (troll2 == troll3) {
            System.out.println("The number " + troll2 + " appears two times.");
            System.out.println("The number " + troll1 + " appears one time.");
        }
    }
    else{

        System.out.println("The entered number is invalid");
    }





}
```

It mostly gives an error when it consists of *digit 5* in the middle. It shows an increment in values and swap in values. Please do help.

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: ```System.out.println("The number " + troll3 + " appears two times.");
                System.out.println("The number " + troll2 + " appears one time.");
            } else if (troll2 == troll3) {
                System.out.println("The number " + troll2 + " appears two times.");
                System.out.println("The number " + troll1 + " appears one time.");
            }
        }
        else{

            System.out.println("The entered number is invalid");
        }





    }```

Some part of the program was deleted I added it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you converting to `float`? `float` and `double` attempts to represent an infinite infinity of numbers (there are an infinite amount of integers. Between 2 integers, there are an infinite amount of numbers too: An infinite amount of infinities)... using only 32 bits. This is obviously impossible so instead only a few numbers are representable, and anything else is silently rounded to one of the select few. This means float and double introduce rounding errors.

After any math done to any double or float, `==` **is broken**. You can't use those; at best, you can try 'delta equality' (not `a == b`, but `Math.abs(a - b) < 0.00001`) but making the claim that your code works for *all* possible inputs becomes very difficult indeed, it's not going to be very fast, and the code readability isn't great either. So, don't.

Stop using floats, problem solved.

Your 'math' to get the individual digits is a bit circumspect and isn't going to just work if you replace things with `int` either. What you're missing is the % operator: Module (a.k.a. remainder).

Given, say, `656`:

```
int in = 657;
int digit1 = in % 10;
in = in / 10;
System.out.println(in); // 65
System.out.println(digit1); // 7
int digit2 = in % 10;
in = in / 10;
System.out.println(in); // 6
System.out.println(digit1); // 5
int digit3 = in;
```

Comment: @Trixie none of what you wrote is correct. [1] Floating point wasn't "precise" pre pentiums. [2] They aren't imprecise primarily because of performance reasons. (They are imprecise because a fixed bit width means you need to make tradeoffs). [3] 1.0 + 1.0 is 2.0. 1.0 is exactly representable. So is 2.0. [4] `strictfp` (which I guess is what you mean with 'strict math' in the context of 'the processor'? ) does not mean there are now no errors.

Comment: For some more detail, @TrixieWolf, pre-pentiums CPUs __couldnt do it__. They needed a separate coprocessor; the 386 had the 387, for example. In the 486 the coprocessor was usually 'built in', from the pentium days, the very concept of a separate coprocessor was abolished. They're now always built in. However, those coprocessors of yore were also IEEE754 based floating point math and make the exact same mistakes. You are possibly thinking of the [`FDIV` bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug#:~:text=The%20Pentium%20FDIV%20bug%20is,in%201994%20by%20Thomas%20R.).

Comment: @rswitserloot I do appreciate the correction about the bug and I have retracted the comment. That said, with respect to "none of what you wrote is correct", I stand by my previous assertion that using a floating point type for discrete data is a fundamental misunderstanding of the best way to think about discrete data. I've seen numerous students in the classroom make the error of treating prices like a floating point value because we use a dot to separate the dollars and the remaining cents. While it can be viewed that way, it's still discrete information (as non-gas prices, anyway).

Comment: @TrixieWolf Your last comment is entirely correct :P

Comment: Good to know. Also, I was fully aware 1.0 etc. is representable (though perhaps bad practice, = with a float untouched by alu ops should work), but not that 1.0 + 1.0 (or similar operations) would reliably translate to exactly 2.0 in all circumstances. Is there a reference you'd prefer for IEEE754 or should I just search online? (Technical is fine: my low rating is because I never post here, not because I'm a layperson.) Thanks again for the correction.

Comment: IEEE doubles consist of 53 bits representing the actual number and then 11 more for the exponent. Thus, all integers below 2^53 are perfectly representable. This includes 1.0 and 2.0.